# Some ASIN can be found through amazon.com but can not be found through API

Tags: c#, amazon-product-api

I facing a problem using amazon product advertizing api.some ASINs can be found if I go to Amazon.com and type it into the search, but it cannot be found through the API call. Does anyone know if there is any reason behind this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please specify the ASIN(s) you are trying to look for and the product advertising api you are trying to use with its associated parameters.

Comment: i am calling amazon Product advertising api 3 oct,2011 , and the asin is B005GRDLNU .

Answer (score 0):

Working fine for me.

Could you try using the ItemLookup operation with the following parameters?

- ItemId: B005GRDLNU
- ResponseGroup: Small

Comment: this is right but how can i get merchant names using ItemLookup opertation.. can u help plz?